# Disable Submit Button or Data Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, button

I am new in creating a script or let say 0 knowledge in using one. I was able to manage to create a database, a simple inventory using google sheet and appscript from a sample in your website. Everything works fine. Here's the script

```
function submitDailySales() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Data Entry"); //Data entry Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Daily Sales"); //Data Sheet
  
  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("D4").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D6").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D8").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D10").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D12").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D14").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D16").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("D18").getValue()]];
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 8).setValues(values);
 
}
```

I need help in not allowing user to submit the data prior to filling out necessary data in D8 and D10. Perhaps via data validation or disabling the button unless field is filled out? Is this possible? Thank you in advance and appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you add the mark up to your question?

Comment: @soupy-norman sorry I am new to this. What do you mean by " add the mark up to your question"

Comment: You are only sharing the script part of your code and it does not reference any button.